# Give free product choice at cart, if savings greater than X - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have a client with a complex requirement that I am struggling to resolve.

They have a set of products on general sale, which have a tag of "f1". The user could purchase this for a normal retail price. However, at the cart page if the user's total savings (made up from sale prices) is greater than X  my client wants to offer the user the choice to have one of the products with a tag of "f1"  as a FREE product instead of having their savings from the sales prices.

Can anyone think of a solution?

- The user must be able to choose between having the savings from the
  sale prices, or taking a free product and paying regular price for
  everything in the cart.
- Also, if the user was to get to cart with just one of these "f1" products in their cart, it should not be free

The below function is what is used to show the user the potential free products. It has a new "reserve" button on the product loop which I had thought to use to add the free product to cart, and apply a coupon code simultaneously

I had tried before with a duplicate set of products, set to zero cost - but the client did not want to maintain duplicate products for this function.

I have another function that works, when a coupon code "giftset" is applied, it resets all cart products to their regular price instead of sale price. I had thought of having this apply when the user chooses to take a free product instead but I couldn't get the code to apply "on click"

Tough one, or am I just amateur? :-(

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'display_freebies' );

//Function to show freebies if discount total is over certain values// 

function display_freebies() {
    
    $discount_total = 0;
    
           foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {         
              $product = $values['data'];
              if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
                 $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
                 $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
                 $discount = ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) * $values['quantity'];
                 $discount_total += $discount;
              }
           }
             
                if ( $discount_total > 10 ) {

            //Product Loop Wrapper
                echo '<div id="freebies"> You may prefer not to use your
                      saving of <span id="freebie_saving">' . wc_price( 
                      $discount_total + WC()->cart->get_discount_total()).'
                      </span>and instead select one of the above items
                      as your gift</div>';
                echo '<div id="freebie_product_wrapper">';
                echo '<div class="woocommerce columns-3">
                <ul class="products columns-3">';

                  //Custom Loop for all products with tag of F1
                    $all_ids = get_posts( array(
                      'post_type' => 'product',
                      'numberposts' => -1,
                      'post_status' => 'publish',
                      'fields' => 'ids',
                      'tax_query' => array(
                         array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => 'F1',
                            'operator' => 'IN',
                         )
                      ),
                   ) );
                 //Change the array slice number to show more/less products
                       foreach ( array_slice($all_ids,0,4) as $id ) {
                    //       echo $id;
                            $product = wc_get_product( $id );
                              $giftname = $product->get_name();
                              $giftimage = $product->get_image();
                              $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                              $regprice = $product->get_regular_price();

                           echo '<li class="product type-product">
                                    <img width="253" height="253" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" src="'. $giftimage .'
                                    <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title freebie_title">';
                            echo $giftname;
                            echo '</h2>
                                      <h2>';
                            echo $currency_symbol .$regprice;
                            echo '</h2>';
                            echo '<div class="product-footer-wrapper" >

                        <a href="' .site_url() .'/bag/?add-to-cart=' .$id .'"><button name="" class="freebie-reserve-button">Reserve</button></a>
                        </li>
                ';
           }
                            echo '</ul> </div>';
            }
}
```

Comment: When I run your code I get the following error: _"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_type() on bool"_, so your question does not contain [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). p.s. code indentation makes your code more readable..

Comment: Many apologies, I left a piece of code in I used on a last trial of desperation before asking for help. It works okay now, and have indented as suggested.

Thank you for any suggestions you may have

Comment: I get the concept. You should also take into account when the customer removes the chosen free product from the cart afterwards or add multiple free products to the cart. 
Therefore your question is actually off-topic. It is not about one specific problem but about a total assignment => _"This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."_